# How to print horizontally when writing into a text file?

Tags: python, list, file, output

I'm trying to print the output like this in a text file:

```
Bruce Wayne
5 5 0 0 100 15
Jessica Jones
12 0 6 6 10 6
Johnny Rose
6 2 0 4 20 10
Gina Linetti
7 4 0 3 300 15
Buster Bluth
3 0 2 1 50 1
```

But with my code here:

```
def write_to_file(filename, player_list):
    outfile = open(filename, "w")

    for i in range(len(player_list)):
        for j in player_list[i]:
           outfile.write(str(j) + '\n')

    outfile.close()
```

It prints out like this:

```
Bruce Wayne
5
5
0
0
100
15
Jessica Jones
12
0
6
6
10
6
Johnny Rose
6
2
0
4
20
10
Gina Linetti
7
4
0
3
300
15
Buster Bluth
3
0
2
1
50
1
```

```
player_list = [['Bruce Wayne', 5, 5, 0, 0, 100, 15], ['Jessica Jones', 12, 0, 6, 6, 10, 6], ['Johnny Rose', 6, 2, 0, 4, 20, 10], ['Gina Linetti', 7, 4, 0, 3, 300, 15], ['Buster Bluth', 3, 0, 2, 1, 50, 1]]
```

and I'm not sure how to get the bottom row to print horizontally like the output I have above. I'm not allowed to use any list functions and I have to use a loop, as seen with my code. Thank you!

Comment: remove the '\n' in your code

Comment: I've tried that but it prints like this now: Bruce Wayne550010015Jessica Jones12066106Johnny Rose62042010Gina Linetti740330015Buster Bluth3021501

Answer (score 2):

You can't treat all the contents of your `player_list` the same, because the values mean different things. The first value is the player name, the rest are scores or something. So your code needs to put a newline after the first value, but only spaces between the rest (with a newline at the end of the second line).

Try something like this:

```
def write_to_file(filename, player_list):
    outfile = open(filename, "w")

    for player_name, *scores in player_list:   # unpack first value separately
        outfile.write(player_name + "\n")
        outfile.write(" ".join(str(score) for score in scores) + "\n")
        
    outfile.close()
```

Unrelatedly, you might want to use `with` to handle your file object. It will close the file automatically for you, even if there's an exception:

```
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    for blah in ...:
        ...
# no need to manually call close(), it will happen automatically here
```

Answer (score 0):

do like so

```
def write_to_file(filename, player_list):
    outfile = open(filename, "w")

    for i in range(len(player_list)):
        for j in player_list[i]:
           outfile.write(str(j))
        outfile.write('\n')

    outfile.close()
```

Comment: Still didn't work, it now prints like this:                                                                               
Bruce Wayne550010015
Jessica Jones12066106
Johnny Rose62042010
Gina Linetti740330015
Buster Bluth3021501

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the player name from the values.

```py
def write_to_file(filename, player_list):
    outfile = open(filename, "w")

    for lst in player_list:
        player = lst[0]
        values = lst[1:]

        outfile.write(player + '\n' + " ".join([str(num) for num in values]) + '\n')


    outfile.close()
```

Comment: I've tried this but the second line with all the numbers doesn't print below the name, which is what I want.